# print report by opening a print dialogue

Tags: c#, activereports

It is fine if I can print report at client side by opening a print dialogue as well without using any Webviewer.

How can i open a print dialogue at client side?

---

**Edit added code from Comments:**

```
rpt.Run();
rpt.Document.Print(false, false, false);
```

I used this code.But this code is server side printer instead of client side printer.Now I want to print directly with print dialogue in Client side

Comment: Please provide more context. What kind of a report? In or with what application? How does the client access the report? On what system?

Comment: rpt.Run(); rpt.Document.Print(false, false, false);                  I used this code.But this code is server side printer instead of client side printer.Now I want to print directly with print dialogue in Client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11419422/51061 . I think this will answer your question completely.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`PrintPreviewControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printpreviewcontrol.aspx), 
[`PrintDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printdocument%28v=vs.90%29)

for printing

```
PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.printDoc_PrintPage);
printDoc.Print()
```

for print preview

```
PrintPreviewDialog dlgPrint = new PrintPreviewDialog();
dlgPrint.Document = printDoc;
dlgPrint.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Can use this code in Activereport direct print?I will test this.But I think it is not comfotable for activereport.Thanks for your answer.

Comment: you cant add this code in activereport directly. just add the active report document as your `PrintDocument' document

Comment: Your Code is for window application. I need for web application.can you tell me how to do?

Comment: check this thread  http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=92&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1